# Does futurizing my Python code would make it dependent on future module.?

Tags: python

The steps I am performing to futurize my code to make it Python 2 & 3 compatible

1. pip install future
2. futurize `--stage1 -w my_module`
3. Verify and update the code for any possible errors

After the steps, my code is (should be) Python 2 & 3 compatible.

My question is,

- Does this conversion make my code dependent on `future` module.!?

From my views, the `futurize` is only a converter and shouldn't make my code dependent. I am still working on actually making the exercise to test this and it would take a long amount of time. It would be really helpful if I get the answer meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer:

```
stage 1 == no dependency
stage 2 == `future` dependency
```

If you check the [documentation](https://python-future.org/futurize.html) you will find that `Stage 1 does not add any imports from the future package`. So as long as you only use stage 1 no dependency to the future module is created. However without stage 2 it is likely that your code will not be fully compatible with either python 2 or 3. If you also run stage 2 you can read the following about it on the linked page `This stage adds a dependency on the future package.`

Comment: Can stage2 code have any other dependencies apart from `future` module. like `lib2to3` or any other.? Or it will only be dependent on future.?